# Rails validating enums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I can't seem to create the following model:

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  enum comparator: [:eq, :gt, :gteq, :lt, :lteq, :not_eq, :in, :matches]

  validates :key, presence: true
  validates :value, presence: true

  validates :comparator, inclusion: { in: [:eq, :gt, :gteq, :lt, :lteq, :not_eq, :in, :matches]}
end
```

Then when I go into the rails console and try to create a new Rule:

```
rule = Rule.new(key: "key", value: "value", comparator: :gteq)
```

I get the following output:

```
=> #<Rule:0x007ff92a4de8f8
id: nil,
key: "key",
value: "value",
comparator: 2,
default: false,
context_id: nil,
created_at: nil,
updated_at: nil>
```

Which looks like the object is valid.  But then I run `rule.valid?` and it returns false.  `rule.errors` returns:

```
#<Rule:0x007ff92a4de8f8
 id: nil,
 key: "key",
 value: "value",
 comparator: 2,
 default: false,
 context_id: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>,
@messages={:comparator=>["is not included in the list"]}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to validate your enums (I believe starting Rails 4.1+) because you will get an `ArgumentError` whenever you try to assign a value not specified previously:

```
rule = Rule.new(key: "key", value: "value", comparator: :fff)
ArgumentError: 'fff' is not a valid comparator
```

Here's some [discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13971) from the core Rails devs when they implemented the change. Hope that helps!